# How to calculate the area of all the subareas in a mesh?

Tags: computational-geometry

I have used Voronoi mesh to generate a mesh of a group of random numbers,

```
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {8, 2}];
mesh = VoronoiMesh[pts]
```

So, it will generate a graph similar to this:

[image: Voronoi]

I want to calculate the area of each mesh grid. Is there any function that can be used to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: `Area /@ MeshPrimitives[mesh,2]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a `MeshRegion`,

```
SeedRandom[420];
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {8, 2}];
mesh = VoronoiMesh[pts]
```

You could get the individual polygons with [`MeshPrimitives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshPrimitives.html) and then use `Area` to find the area.  This was my first thought, but the comments below made me realize it is much faster to use the built-in functions [`PropertyValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PropertyValue.html) and [`MeshCellMeasure`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshCellMeasure.html).  So at the expense of a longer code, this is what we'll use

```
PropertyValue[{mesh, 2}, MeshCellMeasure]
(* {0.439766, 0.51057, 0.373666, 0.494299, 0.734753, 0.387787, 
1.10474, 1.01007} *)
```

As pointed out by J.M. can get the same thing with the built-in, but slightly longer, `PropertyValue[{mesh, 2}, MeshCellMeasure]`.  You can label the cells with the area using [`HighlightMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HighlightMesh.html)

```
HighlightMesh[mesh, 
 MapIndexed[Labeled[{2, First@#2}, #1] &, 
  PropertyValue[{mesh, 2}, MeshCellMeasure]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `PropertyValue[{mesh, 2}, MeshCellMeasure]` will also return the list of areas.

Comment: Thanks, I never look for a built-in when I can work out how to do something.

Comment: Using the `MeshCellMeasure` approach will be faster for large computations, as it does not have to call the evaluator.

Comment: @user21 - So you mean that the cell measures are calculated and stored at the time the meshregion is calculated?

Comment: @JasonB, no they are calculated when requested. But then they are computed in one go. In the `Area` approach each is cell is passed to `Area` and that is equivalent to calling the evaluator. Possibly calling `Area /@...` will also unpack the data.

Comment: @user21 - You are certainly right.  On a larger meshregion the `MeshCellMeasure` version is **much** faster.  If I could have a remedial lesson here - both versions are applying the `Area` function to a group of polygons, but in one you are doing it in one go, and in the other you are pausing in between each call, the pause being the time to exit and recall the evaluator?

Comment: @JasonB, basically internally `MeshCellMeasure` calls a C code version of `Area[allcells]`. On top level things were a bit better if one could call something like `Area[MeshPrimitives[mesh, 2][[All, 1]]]`