# Finding area under a region of a Parametric Plot using mesh functions

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, graphics, mesh, area

I have the following Mathematica code:

```
$Assumptions = {r \[Element] Reals, r >= 0, rh \[Element] Reals, 
   rh > 0, g \[Element] Reals, g > 0, l \[Element] Reals, l > 0};
M[rh_, g_] := (1 + rh^2/l^2) (rh^2 + g^2)^(3/2)/(2 rh^2)
f[r_, rh_, g_] := 1 - (2 M[rh, g] r^2)/(g^2 + r^2)^(3/2) + r^2/l^2
T[rh_, g_] := D[f[r, rh, g], r]/(4 \[Pi]) /. r -> rh
Veff[r_] := f[r, rh, g]*(L^2/r^2)
r0 = Solve[Veff'[r] == 0, r, Reals][[2]]
\[Lambda][rh_, 
   g_] = (Sqrt[-((r^2 f[r, rh, g])/L^2) Veff''[r]]) /. r0 // 
   Simplify;
l = 1;
(tp1 = {#[[1]], \[Lambda][rh1 = (rh /. #[[2]]), 0.02]} &@
      Maximize[{T[rh, 0.02], 0.01 < rh < 1}, rh] // FullSimplify) // N;
(tp2 = {#[[1]], \[Lambda][rh2 = (rh /. #[[2]]), 0.02]} &@
     Minimize[{T[rh, 0.02], rh1 < rh < 1}, rh] // FullSimplify) // N

pplt = ParametricPlot[{T[rh, 0.02], \[Lambda][rh, 0.02]}, {rh, 0.01, 
    8}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 10}}, AspectRatio -> 0.5, 
   PlotPoints -> 50, ImageSize -> 800, 
   PlotTheme -> {"Scientific", "BoldColor"}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Temperature \[Rule]", "Lyapunov Exponent \[Rule]"},
    LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 22}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.004],
   ColorFunction -> 
    Function[{T, \[Lambda], rh}, 
     If[rh <= rh1, Blue, If[rh <= rh2, Red, Green]]], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
   
   Prolog -> {{Gray, Dashing[0.008], Line[{tp1, {tp1[[1]], 0}}], 
      Line[{tp2, {tp2[[1]], 0}}]}, {Darker[Black], 
      Line[{{((tp1 + tp2)/2)[[1]], 0.5}, {((tp1 + tp2)/2)[[1]], 
         9}}]}, {Gray, Thick, Dashing[0.001], Circle[tp1, {0.01, .2}],
       Circle[tp2, {0.01, .2}]}}];

P3 = Legended[pplt, 
  Placed[SwatchLegend[{Blue, Red, Green}, {"Small BH", 
     "Intermediate BH", "Large BH"}, LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 20}, 
    LegendMarkers -> "SphereBubble", LegendMarkerSize -> 20, 
    LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 10, 
        FrameStyle -> None, Background -> GrayLevel[0.95]] &), 
    LegendLabel -> 
     Placed["Black Holes", Left, 
      Rotate[Style[#, 16], 90 Degree] &]], {0.2, .6}]]
```

which gives me the following result:

[image: area]

How can I find the area under Region 1 and Region 2 using Mesh functions ? I also wish to find the position of the line (Basically the value of `T`) for which the Region 1 and Region 2 have equal areas. What approach should I use for that, without succumbing to trial-and-error methods?

Comment: What does the restriction "using mesh functions" mean?

Comment: We can also write λ as a function of T, by substitution which can be used to find the numerical integration using proper limits. This is quite a cumbersome process. I was looking for a way, where I can find the specified area, directly from the plot itself. I have previously seen questions where they talk about finding area using mesh regions in a different context like -> https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119220/78049, So I thought of using such approach for my problem as well.

Comment: @codepr Perhaps my answer is what you're looking for?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann yes it works. Thanks a lot for this! Actually, my main objective was to find the black line which intersects the whole curve into two equal areas, or in other words the value of T, for which a perpendicular line when drawn through it justifies Maxwell construction(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_construction), I think this requires a different question all together. Again, really appreciate your help !

Comment: See  my modified answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope I understood your question correctly.

Using `P3` as start, first take all the points

```
pts = Cases[Normal[P3], Line[p_] :> p, -1][[1]];
```

Now take three subsets defined by range `tp1,tp2`

```
blue = Select[pts, #[[1]] <= tp1[[1]] && #[[2]] >= tp1[[2]] &];
red = Select[pts,tp2[[1]] <= #[[1]] <= tp1[[1]] && tp2[[2]] <= #[[2]] <= tp1[[2]] &] ;
green = Select[pts ,  #[[1]] >=   tp2[[1]] &&   #[[2]] <= tp2[[2]] &] ;
```

Interpolate these points

```
ipblue = Interpolation[blue];
ipred = Interpolation[red];
ipgreen = Interpolation[green];
```

and integrate

```
{Ablue, Ared, Agreen} =NIntegrate[{ipblue[tp], ipred[tp], ipgreen[tp]}, {tp,tp2[[1]],tp1[[1]]}] // Quiet
```

The two areas you 're looking for follow to

```
{Ablue - Ared, Ared - Agreen}
(*{2.82274, 1.9862}*)
```

Hope it helps!

**addendum**

calculation of midpoint `T`

```
reg1[T_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[ ipblue[tp] - ipred[tp] , {tp, T, tp1[[1]]} ]  
reg2[T_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[  ipred[tp] - ipgreen[tp] , {tp, tp2[[1]], T} ]  

line1 = Line[Map[{#, reg1[#]} &, Subdivide[tp2[[1]], tp1[[1]], 20]]];
line2 = Line[Map[{#, reg2[#]} &, Subdivide[tp2[[1]], tp1[[1]], 20]]];
pT=RegionIntersection[line1, line2](*Point[{{0.669968, 0.707078}}]*)

T=pT[[1, 1]][[1]] (*0.669968*)
```

More direct solution using `FindRoot` (NDSolve and NMinimize won't evaluate)

```
T =.
FindRoot[reg1[T] == reg2[T], {T, tp2[[1]], tp1[[1]]}]   
(*{T -> 0.669965} *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the much needed help!

Comment: @codebpr You're welcome

Answer (score 1):

After answering your question, here I'll add a supplement which determines `tp1,tp2` using `MeshFunctions`

```
plot = ParametricPlot[{T[rh, 0.02], \[Lambda][rh, 0.02]}, {rh, 0.01, 
   8}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 10}}, AspectRatio -> 0.5, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, ImageSize -> 800, 
  MeshFunctions -> 
   Function[{x, y, rh}, 
    Evaluate[Derivative[1, 0][ T][rh, 1/50]/1(*Derivative[ 1,
     0][\[Lambda]][rh,1/50]*)]], Mesh -> {{0}}]
```

get points

```
 pts = plot[[1]][[1, 1]]; (* all points*)
 index = Cases[plot, Point[ p_] :>  p, -1][[1]]  (* index meshpoints*)
 tp=pts[[index]] (*{tp1,tp2}*)
 (*{{0.274999, 1.5824}, {0.951599, 7.78498}}*) 

Show[{ListPlot[pts , PlotRange -> All],Graphics[{Red,PointSize[Large], Point[tp]}]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 10}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this :) Just one small doubt. Suppose I fix `T=0.35` (which is basically related to transition temperature for this system) from my side and now wish to find the ratio of the new areas, what tweaks should I make in the previous code snippet of yours?

Comment: Something like `reg1[.35]/reg2[.35]`